# C#: Convert int to char, but in literal not unicode representation

Tags: c#, unicode, char, type-conversion, int

I am trying to convert intergers into characters. But the problem is from what I can tell whenever I convert it turns it into the unicode representation of the char. For example:

```
        int i1 = 3;

        char c1 = (char)i1;
        //also tried: char c1 = Convert.ToChar(i1)

        Console.WriteLine(c1);
```

This is what I'm seeing when I debug:

[image]

It shows 3, which is exactly what I want, I want int 3 to be converted into char '3', but instead it's the unicode representation, '\u0003'. So when I try to print this it results in garbage. I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Comment: you code doesn't include `convert.tochar` , ur picture does..You picture diesn't contain `ii` , but ur code does..You picture include `number` y, your code doesn't...how can we answer such a qs :( ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm sorry for confusion, but the picture is from the actual section of my code. For simplicity sake in this question, and for testing, the code I provided is a simpler way to see what I'm doing, without worry about unnecessary details such as the loop and data structures I was using in the other code. The result from the picture is exactly the same result from the code snipped I provided. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: try the method i provided in the answer , it should work

Comment: @zackraiyan I tried it and it doesnt seem to work because it's having issue converting int into byte. I tried Convert.ToByte(i1) and that didn't work either.

I have solved the problem at this point by making my data structure of type string instead of char, and converting the integers into strings instead of chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you correctly, this is what you want

```
int i1 = 3;
char c = (char)(i1 + '0');

Console.WriteLine(c);
```

`'0'` is 48 in ASCII. Adding 3 to 48 is 51 and converting 51 to char is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

> also tried: char c1 = Convert.ToChar(i1)

If so, try this :

```
 string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{ i1 }); /// here i am keeping the end result a string
```